# How to implement just the wp commenting area on my custom site?

Tags: comments

I'm searching for some site where I can find **line by line** explanation of an wp theme's code.
Because, I want to implement on my site just commenting area.
I don't need sidebar, gadgets, searching, archives... all the toys.
My page has everything I need, except commenting area, but I can't find which code lines stands after pressing "submit" button.
I tried to find such a simple template - without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Twenty Eleven Theme](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/comments.php) has some decent code comments that explain what's happening.

Quick and dirty overview:

All comment functionality goes in `comments.php`.  You include it into your template with the aptly named [`comments_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) which does a lot of stuff (sets up the current commentor, ect) other than just including `comments.php

Your `comments.php` template might look something like this.

```
<?php
// Is the post password protected?  Maybe you want to deal with that.
if(post_password_required())
{
    // show a message to the users about the password requirement.

    // `return` out of the file, don't show anything else
    return;
}

// display the comments if they exist
if(have_comments())
{
    // maybe a header or something here

    // wp_list_comments (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) 
    // actually displays the comments -- it will just work if
    // you use it without any arguments
    wp_list_comments();

    // You can also specify a custom callback to display things:
    // wp_list_comments(array('callback' => 'your_comment_callback'));
}

// are comments open? display the comment form!
if(comments_open())
{
    // `comment_form` does all the work. You can customize it
    // with arguments and filters. Like wp_list_comments this
    // will just work.
    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form
    comment_form();
}
else
{
    // display a message about comments being close for visitors
    // this optional -- personally, I prefer to show no message.
}
```

Take a look at the Twenty Eleven's [comment callback](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php#L518-L573) for some real insight in ways that you can display comments themselves.

Comment: Thanks a lot, chrisguitarguy. I'll study your code and links, and hope this will be solved.